# WCF as a model for MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, model

I am about to start a proof-of-concept project using MVC 4. Unlike Entity Framework, I want to use my own WCF service as a model for this application (as this service handles database access and query formation etc. internally). I understand that "using WCF service as a model" is logical term, what I am looking for is some industry standard best practices to do this. Should I create 'gateway' classes in the model container that actually talks to the service proxy? And handle massaging of data prior to using these gateways in the controller? Any pointer will be appreciated.

Comment: mvc is a presentation layer and has nothing directly to do with data access.  If you are using a web service to access the database, that shouldn't change the mvc set up at all.  For testablility, you may want to write wrappers for the web service classes so that you can mock them and properly unit test any business logic on the client side.  The web service isn't your 'model', it's your data access layer.

Comment: Since the data access logic is integrated inside my WCF and model in MVC represent the underlying back end, Can't I consider WCF as a model and place wrapper / gateway classes that facilitates the service consumption ? Controller will handle data massaging or will have a thin layer of business logic. Am I totally deviating from the MVC concepts? How exactly WCF should be placed and treated inside MVC then?

Comment: Hi @IntelligentBinary, Have you got an answer to your question? if yes, what is the best approach to expose WCF entities as models in MVC application? also, I want to use data annotations for my view models. Can I configure them so in WCF entities?